# PHP read part of large CSV file

Tags: php, csv, parsing

I have a large CSV file. Because of memory concerns (with MySQL), I would like to only read a part of it at a time, if possible.

That it's CSV might not be important. The important thing is that it needs to cut with a new line.

**Example content:**

```
Some CSV content
that will break
on a line break
```

This could be my path:

```
$path = 'path/to/my.csv';
```

**A solution for it could in my mind look like this:**

```
$csv_content1 = read_csv_file($path, 0, 100);
$csv_content2 = read_csv_file($path, 101, 200);
```

1. It reads the raw content on line 0-100.
2. It reads the raw content on line 101-200.

**Information**

- No parsing is needed (just split into content).
- The file exists on my own server.
- Don't read the whole file into the memory.
- I want to be able to do the second read on another time, not on the same run. I accept save temp values like pointers if needed.

I've been trying to read other topics but did not find an exact match to this problem.

**Maybe some of these could somehow work?**

- SplFileObject
- fgetcsv

Maybe I can't use `$csv_content2` before I've used `$csv_content1`, because I need to save some kind of a pointer? In that case it's fine. I will read them in order anyway.

Comment: it seems you need to increase `memory_limit` ?

Comment: The solution is generally to write some code for your `read_csv_file()` function that will do what you want rather than simply posting a specification of your requirements on SO and hoping that somebody will do it for you

Comment: @Noman The filesize I have is unknown. It can be 10MB or 1TB. Probably not but that's the scope I want to count for.

Comment: `fgetscsv` seems like a good option since it will read it like by line. Of course `fopen` with a simple `while` loop is a good alternative too. Increasing `memory_limit` could be an option too but should be left as the last resort. A more brutal method would be to run a shell exec which I do not recommend. Other than that I suppose you could look into some library that would accomplish that for you.

Comment: @Andrew fgetscsv reads line by line but can't start from the middle of the file, right?

Comment: @JensTörnell That's correct, it cannot. The documentation doesn't mention anything about an offset of sorts.

Comment: There is no magic that will start from the middle of the file unless you can know the exact byte position in the file to start at.... if you know that, then you can use `fseek()`; otherwise you'll have to read a line at a time, counting as you go, and discard lines that you don't want to get

Comment: @JensTörnell An alternative, would be `file_get_contents` with `offset` and `maxlen`, but that's sketchy.

Comment: Do you own pointer `$i++` save-and-restore function using a fopen/fwrite/fclose and file_get_contents helper. Then in the next call of your php script, do a big loop discarding all the `fgetcsv` result until you reach the pointer's last value.`if ($i == $last_i)` . It is very quick to code and file access are fast in PHP, faster than an sql query

Comment: @Andrew No answers came in so I added an answer myself. It seems to work perfectly. If you find any flaws of any kind, feedback is welcome.

Comment: Seems good, the only nitpick would be the appending on the `$buffer['content']`. It will get progressively bigger with each iteration. Arguably you're moving the problem of loading the whole file into memory to loading the file into memory but line by line.  On the other hand if you want to write it somewhere or whatever, writing it line by line creates a lot of I/O, so, I dunno,  depends on your needs I guess.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I append the content, but by the limit of in this case 100 times. After that I intend to add it to a databse. After that I don't continue. With the next run, I start from the saved pointer and run through the next 100 rows. I think and hope it's "safe". Thanks for all helpful input.

Comment: Ah oke, that makes sense then. Looks pretty good actually. In theory it shouldn't use a lot of memory(unless you got like 1 huge file that has a single line or something, which hopefully is not the case). Careful with inserting into a loop tho, depending on how large the file is, doing 200-300 queries in a loop maaay not be that great. I don't see another solution to this tho, just pointing it out.

Comment: I take that back, about the query in a loop, I forgot about transactions. Those work pretty nice in this case. Actually I encourage the use of transactions in this particular case. It's the perfect case for all or nothing. Obviously, transactioning a 1gb file will absolutely murder mysql tho.

Comment: @Andrew You are talking about the SQL query insert part? Transactions might work but I have a different approach. Instead of having 100 insert queries I generate only one multiple insert query. It inserts all the 100 rows at the same time. Before this question I tried to insert 10000 rows with a single query. Not very clever, I know. Some PDO timeout. Transactions vs a multiple insert (single query)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After much thinking and reading I finally think I found the solution to my problem. Correct me if this is a bad solution because of memory usage or from other perspectives.

**First run**

```
$buffer = part($path_to_file, 0, 100);
```

**Next run**

```
$buffer = part($path_to_file, $buffer['pointer'], 100);
```

**Function**

```
function part($path, $offset, $rows) {
    $buffer = array();
    $buffer['content'] = '';
    $buffer['pointer'] = array();
    $handle = fopen($path, "r");
    fseek($handle, $offset);
    if( $handle ) {
        for( $i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++ ) {
            $buffer['content'] .= fgets($handle);
            $buffer['pointer'] = mb_strlen($buffer['content']);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return($buffer);
}
```

In my more object oriented environment it looks more like this:

```
function part() {
    $handle = fopen($this->path, "r");
    fseek($handle, $this->pointer);
    if( $handle ) {
        for( $i = 0; $i < 2; $i++ ) {
            if( $this->pointer != $this->filesize ) {
                $this->content .= fgets($handle);
            }
        }
        $this->pointer += mb_strlen($this->content);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: `$this->pointer += mb_strlen($this->content);` is going to cause you problems if your'e using a multibyte character set; fseek() works with bytes, not with characters

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't think so. The mb_strlen calculates the pointer from a multibyte string. The pointer is not multibyte by itself, it's just a position number. When I used strlen it did not find the correct position but when I use mb_strlen it does. I've tried it on 15 position jumps and it finds the correct position every time in my multibyte character file.

Comment: @MarkBaker I tried to change mb_strlen to "UTF-8" to be sure to get all the characters correctly but when I do it does not work anymore. I added a new question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724483/multibyte-pointer-when-reading-part-of-a-file-in-php