# Multibyte pointer when reading part of a file in PHP

Tags: php, string, file, pointers, utf-8

I use PHP.

The function below loads part of a big multibyte enter separated CSV file and return a `pointer` (the end position) and the `content` in an array. With the `pointer` I can later do another run. It works:

```
function part($path, $offset, $rows) {
    $buffer = array();
    $buffer['content'] = '';
    $buffer['pointer'] = array();
    $handle = fopen($path, "r");
    fseek($handle, $offset);
    if( $handle ) {
        for( $i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++ ) {
            $buffer['content'] .= fgets($handle);
            $buffer['pointer'] = mb_strlen($buffer['content']);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return($buffer);
}

// Buffer first part
$buffer = part($path_to_file, 0, 100);

// Buffer second part
$buffer = part($path_to_file, $buffer['pointer'], 100);

print_r($buffer);
```

**If I change the `$buffer['pointer']` line to:**

```
$buffer['pointer'] = mb_strlen($buffer['content'], "UTF-8");
```

...it does not work anymore... I understand that it uses the different encoding when I use UTF-8 instead of the default, but why doesn't it work with UTF-8?

**Shouldn't UTF-8 be compatible with foreign characters?**

Because the function above works when I use it without "UTF-8" I guess I could just use it without UTF-8.

**I'm still worried that in some cases it can give the wrong pointer?**

**Is there a safer way to get the correct pointer?**

### Encoding test

When I do this I get `UTF-8`:

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($buffer['content']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has little to do with UTF-8. Filesystem functions (like `fseek()`, `fread()`, etc.) operate on individual bytes. They don't care about the encoding at all. (You could be writing / reading binary data).

If you want to store a pointer to `fseek()` to at a later time, use [`ftell()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php) to find out the current position:

```
$buffer['pointer'] = ftell($handle);
```

Comment: I tried `ftell` and it did not work. I ended up with the wrong pointer again. So far the only thing that has worked is `$this->pointer += mb_strlen($this->content);` but I have hard to accept things I don't understand.

Comment: ShiraiNai7 is correct. If you're having a problem using ftell() then your code is wrong. Using strlen on the accumulated data repeatedly to measure its size is *horrible*.

Comment: @symcbean Yes, I agree with you now. It seems like I was doing something wrong. I rewrote it and it does work. Thanks!